# Query for union and grouping of some rows by column values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, union

I have a table called Products. I am trying to write a query to sum the values of `total_amt` and `total_num` based on `year` and `product_code`.

`total_amt_by_prod` and `total_num_by_prod` are the expected outputs.

| year | product_code | amt1 | amt2 | amt3 | total_amt | total_amt_by_prod | num1 | num2 | num3 | total_num | total_num_by_prod |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | LA2013288 | 10000 | NULL | NULL | 10000 | 10000 | 4 | 1 | 3 | 8 | 8 |
| 2021 | XS2014184 | NULL | NULL | 103330531 | 103330531 | 291396632 | 1 | NULL | NULL | 1 | 3 |
| 2021 | XS2014184 | NULL | NULL | 90404990 | 90404990 | 291396632 | 1 | NULL | NULL | 1 | 3 |
| 2021 | XS2014184 | NULL | NULL | 97661111 | 97661111 | 291396632 | 1 | NULL | NULL | 1 | 3 |
| 2022 | XS2014184 | NULL | NULL | 52648 | 52648 | 52648 | 1 | NULL | NULL | 1 | 1 |

What I have so far:

```
SELECT 
    *,
    NVL(amt1, 0) + NVL(amt2, 0) + NVL(amt3, 0) total_amt,
    NVL(num1, 0) + NVL(num2, 0) + NVL(num2, 0) total_num
FROM Products
```

I don't know how to obtain the values of `total_amt_by_prod` and `total_num_by_prod`.

Comment: Have you considered/tried a window function?

Comment: Why does product code XS2014.. "total amount by prod" have two distinct values? Is it actually "total amount by prod by year"?

Comment: @CaiusJard yes, it is by year and product

Comment: @DaleK removed the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Total amount by product, by year..

```
SUM(NVL(amt1, 0) + NVL(amt2, 0) + NVL(amt3, 0)) OVER(PARTITION BY year, product_code)
```

And do similar for the num

OVER/PARTITION BY is a bit like asking the db to run a subquery that groups by the partition and sums whatever is in the sum, then auto join it back to each row based on the values of year,product_code

ie in normal terms you're probably more familiar with it's like

```
FROM Products
INNER JOIN (SELECT year, product_code, sum(..) as total_by_year_prod FROM Products GROUP BY year, product_code) x 
  USING(year, product_code)
```

Which you could also do, if you don't get on with window functions (but they're a slightly more optimal route)

Incidentally, if here will only ever be a value in one of the amt columns you can neaten the code up to:

```
COALESCE(amt1,amt2,amt3,0)
```

COALESCE works left to right picking the first non null argument it encounters

Comment: I used OVER/PARTITION. Thanks for the answer! There are values in both amt1, amt2 and amt3 but I just didn't show all rows. COALESCE is a new concept to me, thanks for adding this in your answer too!

Answer (score -1):

```
select year, product_code, 
    sum(isnull(amt1, 0) + isnull(amt2, 0) + isnull(amt3, 0)) total_amt, 
    sum(isnull(num1, 0) + isnull(num2, 0) + isnull(num2, 0)) total_num
from Products
group by year, product_code
```

Comment: I good answer includes a description of how you are solving the problem in addition to working code.